# Flutter , need help on how to make it become tabitems

Tags: flutter

Im new to flutter and I follow youtube and got this bottom navigators. Is there anyway how should I change it become tabitems ?

I have search alot of tabitems but I dun know how to convert it .

Will be happy if someone solved my problem!
Will be happy if someone solved my problem!
Will be happy if someone solved my problem!
Will be happy if someone solved my problem!

```
class BottomNavigationEzyMember extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigationEzyMember({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomNavigationEzyMemberState createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationEzyMemberState();
}

class _BottomNavigationEzyMemberState extends State<BottomNavigationEzyMember> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  var bottomTextStyle =
      GoogleFonts.inter(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500);

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 64,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: mFillColor,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
            spreadRadius: 2,
            blurRadius: 15,
            offset: const Offset(0, 5),
          )
        ],
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
          topRight: Radius.circular(24),
        ),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 0
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home.svg'),
            title: Text('Home', style: bottomTextStyle),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 1
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/order_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/order.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'My Card',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 2
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/watch_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/watch.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'Watch List',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 3
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/account_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/account.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'Account',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: mBlueColor,
        unselectedItemColor: mSubtitleColor,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedFontSize: 12,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `tabitems`?

Comment: @novol what I means is the bottom navigation bar can appear at all screen and navigate to other screen while the bottom navigation bar still there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you searching this. Using this code you can appear bottom navigation bar to your all screens

```
int _selectedIndex = 0;

final _homeScreen = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _accountScreen = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _profileScreen = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedIndex,
        children: <Widget>[
          Navigator(
            key: _homeScreen,
            onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: route,
              builder: (context) => Home(),
            ),
          ),
          Navigator(
            key: _accountScreen,
            onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: route,
              builder: (context) => Account(),
            ),
          ),
          Navigator(
            key: _profileScreen,
            onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: route,
              builder: (context) => Profile(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            canvasColor: Colors.white,
            splashColor: Color(0xffFFED31),
            unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white,
            primaryColor: Color(0xffFFED31),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff3A3A3A),
            textTheme: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .copyWith(caption: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Container(
                  height: 20.0,
                  width: 20.0,
                  child: _selectedIndex == 0
                      ? SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/home.svg",
                          color: Color(0xffFFED31), semanticsLabel: 'home')
                      : SvgPicture.asset(AppConfig.classes,
                          color: Colors.white, semanticsLabel: 'home')),
              title: Text(
                'Home',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Container(
                  height: 20.0,
                  width: 20.0,
                  child: _selectedIndex == 1
                      ? SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/account.svg",
                          color: Color(0xffFFED31), semanticsLabel: 'schedule')
                      : SvgPicture.asset(AppConfig.schedule,
                          color: Colors.white, semanticsLabel: 'schedule')),
              title: Text(
                'Account',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Container(
                  height: 20.0,
                  width: 20.0,
                  child: _selectedIndex == 2
                      ? SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/profile.svg",
                          color: Color(0xffFFED31), semanticsLabel: 'profile')
                      : SvgPicture.asset(AppConfig.storeIcon,
                          color: Colors.white, semanticsLabel: 'profile')),
              title: Text(
                'Profile',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: (val) => _onTap(val, context),
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff3A3A3A),
          selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Color(0xffFFED31)),
          unselectedLabelStyle:
              TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Color(0xffFFFFFF)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

void _onTap(int val, BuildContext context) {
    if (_selectedIndex == val) {
      switch (val) {
        case 0:
          _homeScreen.currentState.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
          break;
        case 1:
          _accountScreen.currentState.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
          break;
        case 2:
          _profileScreen.currentState.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
          break;

        default:
      }
    } else {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = val;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Navigate like this if you want bottom navigation bar appear to next screen

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext c) => NextScreen()));
```

Navigate like this if you want bottom navigation bar doesn't appear to next screen

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext c) => NextScreen()));
```

Answer (score 0):

not really sure if I understood you, but it seems you need this

```
class BottomNavigationEzyMember extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigationEzyMember({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomNavigationEzyMemberState createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationEzyMemberState();
}

class _BottomNavigationEzyMemberState extends State<BottomNavigationEzyMember> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  var bottomTextStyle =
      GoogleFonts.inter(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500);

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _getBody(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 0
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home.svg'),
            title: Text('Home', style: bottomTextStyle),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 1
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/order_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/order.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'My Card',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 2
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/watch_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/watch.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'Watch List',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 3
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/account_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/account.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'Account',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: mBlueColor,
        unselectedItemColor: mSubtitleColor,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedFontSize: 12,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getBody( )  {
    if(selectedIndex == 0) {
      return Text('first');
    } else if(selectedIndex == 1) {
      return Text('second');
    } else if(selectedIndex == 2) {
      return Text('third');
    } else if(selectedIndex == 3) {
      return Text('last screen');
    } else {
      return Text('not in index');
    }
  }
}
```

I advise you to use the documentation, not videos on youtube, look to flutter official code sample https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html#material.BottomNavigationBar.1

Comment: the flutter official is the thing that I wanted, but I dun know how to navigate to a new page (new dart file)

Comment: create new file like first_screen.dart and into file create class `FirstScreen` also replace it `return Text('first');` on it `return FirstScreen();`